# Winjs.xhr, Visual Studio and offline server

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, winjs

I'm here because of a bug on my visual studio. I created a Windows Store Application for Windows 8.1 in Javascript and I have some troubles with visual studio.

Here is the script:

login.html

```
        <div class="login">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username" required><br />
            <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required><br />
            <button onclick="login()">Ok</button>
        </div>
```

login.js

```
function login() {
    var body = {};
    body.name = document.getElementById("inputUsername").value;
    body.password = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value;

    var promise = WinJS.xhr({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:598/session",
        data: JSON.stringify(body),
        responseType: "json",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    }).done(
        function completed(result) {
            var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
            console.log(response);
        },
        function error(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
};
```

The problem is the following : When I switch off the localhost server and when I launch the login function, the debugger of visual studio crash and tell me nothing about the javascript error or something else...
And if the localhost is on, the debugger is working well.

Someone have the solution ?

Thanks,

Oxyno-zeta

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it was a bug in javascript. Visual studio doesn't like wrong function call.
Sorry !

Thanks,

Oxyno-zeta